# Subtract two timespec objects; find difference in time or duration

Tags: c, time

The `clock_gettime` function requires a `struct timespec` object as an argument.

https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

In the date and time utilities section of the C standard library, there is a function `difftime` which calculates the difference in two `time_t` objects.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono

However there does not appear to be an equivalent function for `struct timespec` data.

I guess it is trivial to write one given that there are just two fields inside of a `struct timespec` (one for the number of seconds and one for the number of nanoseconds). However, it seems surprising that the standard library does not include this function for convenience.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
(time_stop.tv_sec - time_start.tv_sec)
    + 1.0e-9 * (time_stop.tv_nsec - time_start.tv_nsec);
```

Does a function to find the difference in time between two `struct timespec` objects exist? Or is it perhaps not included because `clock_gettime` can be called with different arguments for different *types* of clock?

Comment: Good, convenient utility functions for manipulating `struct timespec` (and the older `struct timeval` — it'd be nice to have a set of those, too) are *not* always so trivial to write.  I wish there were a standard set, too.  I suspect the reason is that C has never sought to be voluminous or complete in that sort of way.

Comment: There is at least one theoretical case where a hypothetical `timespec_diff` function would not be sufficient, or would need an extra `flags` argument or something.  *If* you implemented the `CLOCK_UTC` clock described at https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/posix-clocks.html, you'd want a way to take differences between two of those values that either did or didn't honor leap seconds, or that returned an error if the computation were impossible due to leapsecond ambiguity or lack of sufficient leapsecond information.

Comment: @SteveSummit Many systems have macros for working with timeval structs, but not timespec for some reason. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timeradd.3.html

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant, Anything more on this question that I may help you with?

Answer (score 6):

> However, it seems surprising that the standard library does not include this function for convenience.

> Does a function to find the difference in time between two struct timespec objects exist?

`double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0)` returns *seconds*, regardless of the time units and type used for `time_t`.

`time_t` is some real type, often in seconds, but not specified as such.

`difftime()` performs the subtraction and returns *seconds*.  User code cannot as there is no seconds per `time_t` constant,

`struct timespec` is specified to use seconds and nanoseconds, so a time difference in units and desired type is readily code-able.

---

Perhaps as:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>

struct timespec diff_timespec(const struct timespec *time1,
    const struct timespec *time0) {
  assert(time1);
  assert(time0);
  struct timespec diff = {.tv_sec = time1->tv_sec - time0->tv_sec, //
      .tv_nsec = time1->tv_nsec - time0->tv_nsec};
  if (diff.tv_nsec < 0) {
    diff.tv_nsec += 1000000000; // nsec/sec
    diff.tv_sec--;
  }
  return diff;
}
```

OR

```
double diff_timespec(const struct timespec *time1, const struct timespec *time0) {
  return (time1->tv_sec - time0->tv_sec)
      + (time1->tv_nsec - time0->tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}
```

---

`time.h` is missing much: `mktime_utc()`, robust timezone support, etc.

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant `* 1e9` and `/ 1e9`  make for slightly different results.  `/ 1e9` being the better one.  Consider posting an alternative if  you like.

Comment: I'd say that tantalizing comment is worth at least a pointer to a reference!  (And did you mean `* 1e-9`?)

Comment: Sorry did I miss a minus sign from the edit?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant,  Yes I meant `1.0e-9`.   Consider if `* 1e-9` and `/ 1e9` did not differ, the compiler could encode either way and so use the most efficient.  So if the same, it makes no difference, but if different, which is better?  1.0e-9, as a `double` is more like `0.000000001000000000000000062...` as the `double` constant itself is not 1.0e-9.  OTOH `/ 1.0e9` is division with an exact desired constant.  If more needed, consider posting a question.  Given the exactitudes of _time_, generating the best answer is called for, even if it costs a division vs. multiplication.

Comment: If you take a casual stroll through the park the uncertainty caused by time dilation due to your movement will be many orders of magnitude more than the difference between /1e9 and *1e-9. There's no human-made clock that could measure time that accurately.

Comment: @JimmyMcHoover Although the practicality of your comment is about time is truthful, the goal of repeatability of code comes into play.  With variant implementations that differ by as small as a [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), do we accept both, or the better one?  Much analysis of FP  code is triggered by such off-by-1  cases.  There are less discrepancies when each implementation forms the best answer.