# how to get a delta-time by seconds in int32 and nanosecond in uint32 for cpp

Tags: c++, overflow

i got some timestamp where seconds in int32 and nanosecond in uint32, i wish to get a accuracy delta-time, like:

```cpp
int32   last_seconds; // = some value
int32   this_seconds; // = some value
uint32  last_nanosec; // = some value, e.g. 178922366
uint32  this_nanosec; // = some value, e.g. 58887157


float delta_seconds = float(this_seconds - last_seconds);
float delta_nanosec = float(this_nanosec - last_nanosec);

float delta_time = delta_seconds + delta_nanosec/1e9;
```

but i found `this_nanosec - last_nanosec` easily overflow as they are `uint32` and frequently `this_nanosec < last_nanosec`, as example `delta_nanosec = 4.17493`, but `delta_nanosec = -0.120035209` is more reasonable . (however, results of `seconds` look fine)

how can i get a accuracy delta-time as expected in this case? thanks

Comment: Use `unit64_t`? Why don't you use specialized types, lile `std::chrono::duration`?

Comment: `delta_seconds + delta_nanosec` doesn't make sense, since they're different units. You need to divide the nanoseconds value by 1 billion somewhere to convert them to seconds (or multiply the seconds by 1 billion to convert them to nanoseconds).

Comment: For anything related to time I recommend using std::chrono. It has all the functionality you need. e..g you could write  `using namespace std::chrono_literals; auto duration = 1s + 1ns;` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22ns). An advantage to using chrono is on your function signatures you can make clear you expect a time unit and not just a random floating point number (semantics)

Comment: @Kevin, sorry, mistake...should be `float delta_time = delta_seconds + delta_nanosec/1e9;` as edited

Comment: If you know that the nanoseconds will always be in the range of 0 to 1e9-1 store them as a signed int so the subtraction can go negative instead of overflow (underflow?) back to a large positive value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your input timestamps to initialize `timespec` struct/s, then plug them in [diff_timespec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68804612/10479210)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <iostream>

double diff_timespec(const struct timespec *time1, const struct timespec * time0) 
{
    return (time1->tv_sec - time0->tv_sec) + (time1->tv_nsec - time0->tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    int32_t   last_seconds = 3; // = some value
    uint32_t  last_nanosec = 178922366; // = some value, e.g. 178922366

    int32_t   this_seconds = 6; // = some value
    uint32_t  this_nanosec = 58887157; // = some value, e.g. 58887157

    struct timespec last{last_seconds, last_nanosec}, now{this_seconds, this_nanosec};


    double delta_time = diff_timespec(&now, &last);
    std::cout << delta_time << std::endl;
}
```

---

output: 2.87996

Comment: exactly what i want, thx